# Making an app accessible via two domains for same-origin AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, same-origin-policy

**Before you tell me about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and whitelisting, assume for the sake of argument that I can't touch the HTTP headers.**

**This is a hypothetical question.**

---

My question:

- let's say I have an app available at a domain and I want to send a POST request from another domain, but I own both domains.
- let's also say, for the sake of argument, that I'm not at liberty to adjust CORS settings

So I can make an ajax request from `website.com` to `app.website.com`. but I have a second website, `website2.com`, which would also like to make an ajax request to `app.website.com`

If I were to create two CNAME records for `app.website.com` so that `app.website2.com` would point to the same app, could I then make an ajax request from either domain without necessitating the setting of `Access-Control` headers?

As far as I can tell, the only problem would be a possible SEO penalty from Google for not having a canonical URL for app.website.com, which is irrelevant as in my thought experiment it's basically just an endpoint.

Anybody illuminate me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comply to the same hostname restriction (including the subdomain) then you can indeed use a CNAME to allow both domains to point to the same server.

If your question is about whether the name resolution of the CNAME is of importance for the CORS, then answer is "no it is not considered" and thus you can use this trick.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping I'd hear that!

Answer (score 0):

The Same-Origin Policy judges by *hostname* (as part of the origin), not physical server.

You can't do that.

To put it differently, if you use shared hosting, you must not get access to anyone else on that shared server.

Instead, you can use JSONP.